# rails server -d is not running as a background process

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, shell, blocking

I currently have the below command running as a batch script

/usr/local/rvm/wrappers/ruby-1.8.7-p358/ruby /var/rails/sandbox/script/server -p 8080 -e sandbox -d
However the log ends at trying to initialize 0.0.0.0 8080
if I remove the -d so the script is 
/usr/local/rvm/wrappers/ruby-1.8.7-p358/ruby /var/rails/sandbox/script/server -p 8080 -e sandbox
then everything runs perfect.  The only issue is I am trying to detach the output so I can reuse the terminal session. 
Please let me know if there is something I need to run?

Also just an fyi if I were to run the script/server alone I would have to use rvmsudo script/server -p 8080 -e sandbox -d, I get the same issue of it trying to end at 0.0.0.0 8080 but my site will not run and I will not get the message WEBrick::HTTPServer#start

Comment: You could use `nohup` command if you on linux or unix-like OS.

Comment: how would I use the nohup command with this?

Comment: `nohup /usr/local/rvm/wrappers/ruby-1.8.7-p358/ruby /var/rails/sandbox/script/server -p 8080 -e sandbox`

Comment: I tried that now I am getting stuck on my terminal with nohup: ignoring input and redirecting stderr to stdout, I also tried nohup /rvm/wrappers/ruby-1.8.7-p358/ruby /var/rails/sandbox/script/server -p 8080 -e sandbox > /dev/null

Comment: Well, after `nohup` try to type ctrl-z and then enter `bg` command

Comment: whats the bg command?

Comment: Just type `bg` on console and press `enter` )

Comment: nevermind I saw it worked, so now how do I put the bg command into a shell script?

Comment: If you need it to run from script just put ` &` at the end of yours nohup line. No needs in ctrl-z and bg in this case.

Comment: that does not work I still get the nohup: redirecting stderr to stdout and then it errors out

Comment: Well,, you should investigate it as at this point it works for me.

Comment: Does anyone else have any ideas?